# How to use options property with SDWebImagePrefetch?

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

This might be simple question to some, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to apply `options` property for [SDWebImagePrefetcher](https://sdwebimage.github.io/Classes/SDWebImagePrefetcher.html#/c:objc(cs)SDWebImagePrefetcher(py)options)

Thus far I set it up to fetch some urls with completion block

```
SDWebImagePrefetcher.shared.prefetchURLs(
        urls as [URL],
        progress: nil,
        completed: { finished, skipped in
          print("Finished")
        }
      )
```

I think options are set up like this? But I am not sure what needs to come instead of `/* ? */` in order to enable one of the options `SDWebImageCacheMemoryOnly`

```
SDWebImagePrefetcher.shared.options = /* ? */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`options` is of type `SDWebImageOptions`, which is declared using the `NS_OPTIONS` macro. This means you can combine options using the bitwise or operator in Objective-C:

```
SDWebImagePrefetcher.shared.options = SDWebImageRetryFailed | SDWebImageLowPriority; // etc
```

Or like this in Swift:

```
SDWebImagePrefetcher.shared.options = [.retryFailed, .lowPriority] // etc
```

All the options can be found here: https://sdwebimage.github.io/Enums/SDWebImageOptions.html